# Left alignment for last line of textlayoutformat

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I set `textLayoutFormat.textAlign = TextAlign.JUSTIFY;` for following tlf

```
sample text sample text sample text
sample text sample text sample text
             sample text
```

but it look like this

```
sample text sample text sample text
sample text sample text sample text
sample                         text
```

I want to set left align for last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `textAlignLast` property.

Example:

```xml
<s:TextArea
    textAlign="justify"
    textAlignLast="right"
    text="sample text sample text sample text
    sample text sample text sample text
    sample text
    "/>
```

outputs:

```
sample text sample text sample text
sample text sample text sample text
                        sample text
```

Notice that `textAlignLast` works only for justified text.

Comment: textLayoutFormat.textAlign = TextAlign.JUSTIFY; textLayoutFormat.textAlignLast = TextAlign.LEFT; I am doing same but its not working

Comment: weird, did you try to apply `align and alignLast` to the component itself instead textlayoutformat?