# Last line alignment for textArea in Flex 3

Tags: css, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

```
txtArea.setStyle("textAlign","justify");
```

Shows text like

```
textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample
textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample
textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample textSample
textSample
```

Last line is not justified in text area. Is it possible to align last line in flex 3. Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `textAlignLast` property:

```
txtArea.setStyle("textAlign", "justify");
txtArea.setStyle("textAlignLast", "justify"); /*or "center", "left", "right"*/
```

Comment: Does Flex 3 support this property. Actually it is not working may have other problem too.

Comment: @Sarang I'm not sure whether it's supported in **Flex 3**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8714900/364869